# Determine the value of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)\cdot(1-p)^{2k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you determine the following series step by step?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)\cdot(1-p)^{2k}\qquad \text{with }p\leq 1
$$

Wolfram Alpha gives me the following solution:
$$
\frac{1}{(p-2)^2\cdot p^2} \quad \text{when }p^2\leq 2\cdot Re(p)
$$

Unfortunately, even though I have a pro account it doesn't give me a step-by-step solution to this problem. I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: Do you know how to compute a closed-form expression for  $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1) x^k$ for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$ (Hint: power series, term-wise integration). If so, take $x=(1-p)^2$ in the result, i.e. evaluate $f((1-p)^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering $$A=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)\cdot(1-p)^{2k}$$ first define $x=(1-p)^2$ which gives $$A=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)\cdot x^{k}=\frac d {dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty  x^{k+1}\right)=\frac d {dx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty  x^{k}\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thanks. I see. For $(1-p)^2 <1$, we can use the formula for geometric series. Thereafter we derivate it. And finally we backsubstitute $x$ and simplify to get the result. For $p=1$ the sum diverges.

Comment: You got it and you are very welcome !